# Verilog/Xilinx Vivado Multidriven Net

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, xilinx

I am trying to implement a TPU like SoC and seem to have a bug in one of my modules.

Here is the code for that module:

```vhdl
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module acc #(
    parameter data_size = 8,
    parameter array_size = 3
) (
    input clk,
    input en,
    input wire [0:(data_size * array_size)-1] from_array, // all lines of the systolic array
    output wire [0:data_size-1] conv // The final result on a discrete convolution 
);
    // The shift register size is always ((array_size-1)*2 + 1)*d  where array_size is the size of the kernel, and d the data size
    localparam shift_reg_size = (((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1) * data_size);
    // The size of cpt is proportionate to the shift register size
    reg [0:$clog2((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1)-1] cpt = 0;
    reg [0:shift_reg_size - 1] shift = 0;
    // The last cell of the shift register is always the result of the convolution stage.
    assign conv = shift[shift_reg_size - data_size : shift_reg_size - 1];
    // Generate the shift adder logic
    genvar i;
    generate
        for (i = 1; i < array_size; i = i + 1) begin : shift_gen
            always @(negedge clk) begin  : shift_gen_level
                localparam j = ((i-1)*2+1);
                if (en && cpt > j) begin
                    shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] + from_array[i*data_size:(i+1)*data_size-1];
                end
            end  
        end
    endgenerate

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (en) begin
            shift <= {from_array[0:data_size-1],shift[0:shift_reg_size - data_size - 1]};
            // Stop incrementing when have reached the top
            cpt <= cpt == {($clog2((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1)-1){1'b1}} ? cpt : cpt + 1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Let me try to explain the general functionality of this module without going into too much detail, as it may help to understand the issue. The shift register will receive the first **data_size** bits from the **from_array** input on every posedge. And of course the value stored in the last shift register cell will be overwritten. The counter `cpt` will also increment, this counter allows for some additional logic to be performed during the negedge. On the negedge if the **cpt** is large enough, the value currently stored at certain cells of the shift register will get incremented by incoming values from the **from_array**.
One last thing is that the last **data_size** bits of the shift register are directly connected (via the assign), to the conv output.

The multidriven net error occurs on the generated portion of the code, so the adder logic of the design.

To complete the picture, I must add that the simulation works correctly and gives the desired functionality,

One idea I had is that happens because of the fact that I do the assign to the **conv** as well as distinct operations on the **shift** register during posedge and negedge. But that does not make much sense as I have used a similar design pattern elsewhere and it worked like a charm!

I have also changed my logic to work on the posedge only. I also added a state machine to alternate between the **shift_state** and the **add_state**. However I still seem to get the multi-driven net between my two assignments to **shift**. I don not understand why, because clearly both of those assignments are differed by the state register. Could someone give me a clue on what am I doing wrong?

```vhdl
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module acc #(
    parameter data_size = 8,
    parameter array_size = 3
) (
    input clk,
    input en,
    input wire [0:(data_size * array_size)-1] from_array, // all lines of the systolic array
    output wire [0:data_size-1] conv // The final result on a discrete convolution 
);
    // The shift register size is always ((array_size-1)*2 + 1)*d  where array_size is the size of the kernel, and d the data size
    localparam shift_reg_size = (((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1) * data_size);
    // The size of cpt is proportionate to the shift register size
    reg [0:$clog2(((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1)*2)-1] cpt = 0;
    reg [0:shift_reg_size - 1] shift = 0;

    // Memorise
    reg [0:(data_size * array_size)-1] shift_mem = 0;
    reg [0:data_size-1] conv_ = 0;
    // The last cell of the shift register is always the result of the convolution stage.
    assign conv = conv_;

    // State machine
    localparam add_state = 0;
    localparam shift_state = 1;
    reg state = shift_state;
    // Generate the shift adder logic
    genvar i;
    generate
        for (i = 1; i < array_size; i = i + 1) begin : shift_gen
            always @(posedge clk) begin  : shift_gen_level
                localparam j = ((i-1)*2+1);
                if (en && cpt/2 > j && state == add_state && state != shift_state) begin
                    shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] + shift_mem[i*data_size:(i+1)*data_size-1];
                end
            end  
        end
    endgenerate
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (en) begin
            if (state == shift_state && state != add_state) begin
                state <= add_state;
            end
            else if (state == add_state && state != shift_state) begin
                state <= shift_state;
            end

            if (state == shift_state && state != add_state) begin
                shift <= {shift_mem[0:data_size-1],shift[0:shift_reg_size - data_size - 1]};               
            end
            // Stop incrementing when have reached the top
            cpt <= cpt == {{1'b1},{($clog2(((array_size - 1) * 2 + 1)*2)-1){1'b0}}} ? cpt : cpt + 1;
            shift_mem <= from_array;
            conv_ <= shift[shift_reg_size - data_size : shift_reg_size - 1];
        end

    end
endmodule
```

I would appreciate if someone could tell me where my error comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make assignments to `shift` from 2 `always` blocks.  That is considered a multidriven net by  the tool (Vivado/Xilinx).  It does not matter to the tool that you are making assignments on the opposite edges of the clock.

1st `always` block:

```
        always @(negedge clk) begin  : shift_gen_level
           ...
                shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] <= shift[j*data_size:(j+1)*data_size-1] + from_array[i*data_size:(i+1)*data_size-1];
```

2nd `always` block:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
   ...
            shift <= {shift_mem[0:data_size-1],shift[0:shift_reg_size - data_size - 1]};
```

You should only make assignments to a signal from a single `always` block.  You need a new design approach.